# How can I add a key-value pair to a Containers.Map object?

Tags: matlab, mapping

## Question

I have a [`Containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html) object with 155 key-value pairs. I would like to add a key-value pair to that object, is there a function that allows me to do this easily?

## Starting situation

```
keys = {'apples', 'bananas', 'lemons', 'oranges'};
values = {1, 2, 3, 4};
M = containers.Map(keys, values);
```

## What have I tried

### Using the [`add`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/add.html) function

```
add(M, 'peaches', '5')
```

`Undefined function 'add' for input arguments of type 'containers.Map'.`

### Re-creating the Containers.Map object

```
keys = N.keys
values = N.values
keys = [keys, 'peaches']
values = [values, 5]
M = containers.Map(keys, values)
```

This works, but is cumbersome to do, so can be seen as a workaround.
I am hoping to find a function similar to [`remove`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.remove.html).

Comment: Did you try `M('peaches')=5`?

Comment: I did not, thanks for the fast response. Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add keys to the map simply by indexing to the new key and assigning:

```
M('peaches') = 5;
```